# Pass an Text Field input from one class to another in Android

Tags: java

I'm working in Android studio and I set up a Text Field widget in my MainActivity class for the user to enter their name. When the use enters their name and clicks the login button I also set up, I want a "Hello, 'name'" string to appear. How do I pass the name input to the my SecondActivity.java class?

Comment: use intent to pass data between activities

Answer (score 1):

```
Textview textview = new (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1)
TextView TV2 = new (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2)
Button Login = new (Button)findViewByID(R.id.button1)
Login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(...{

  //Do anything you want to, like:
 TV2.setText("Welcome " +textView.getText().toString() );
}
```

And when you want to pass data:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContent, ....)
i.putExtra(String(then add textview.getText.toString()))
startActivity(i)
```

Hope this helps, but please google this next time

Comment: @Kushan true, lets get rid of all of these comments, not very relevant :D

Answer (score 1):

Use an Intent:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("name",youttextinput.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

You can then get it using:

```
String yourName=getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
```